# SELECT WHERE '".$Variables."'='YES'

Tags: php, select, mysqli

i want to select from table any row 
that has `column (admin, normal, adviser)` and `="YES"`

so i created an `array $level=array(admin, normal, advuser)`
if the user is `admin ==> $level[0]`

`$query="SELECT * FROM LibraryFolders WHERE '".$level[0]."'='YES'";`

how to but a Variables as column key

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `'` around the column name

```
$query="SELECT * FROM LibraryFolders WHERE ".$level[0]." = 'YES'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$filter = "";
if($user == 'admin') {
    $filter = " {$level[0]} = 'YES' ";
}
elseif($user == 'normal') {
    $filter = " {$level[1]} = 'YES' ";
}
else {
    $filter = " {$level[2]} = 'YES' ";
}
$query= "SELECT * FROM LibraryFolders WHERE {$filter} ";
```

but we need more information: How do you get the array?

hope be helpful